# AndroidエミュレータがVisual Stuioのデバッグターゲットに表示されない

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio

以下の手順でAndroidエミュレータを起動したのですがVisual Studioのデバッグターゲットにエミュレータが表示されません。
Visual StudioにAndroidエミュレータを認識させるにはどうすればよろしいのでしょうか？

1. 「Android Virtual Device (ADV)Manager」を起動(※:1)
2. エミュレータを起動し、「Dev Settings」→「USB debugging」にチェックを入れる(※:2)
3. 「Visual Studio」を起動し、「テンプレート」→「Visual C++」→「クロスプラットフォーム」→「Native-Activity」でプロジェクトを作成(※:3)
4. デバッグターゲットに「Debug」「x86」「使用可能なデバイスが存在しません」と表示されてしまう。
5. 「F5」でビルド＆実行すると「パッケージのインストール中にエラーが発生しました。デバイス '' が無効か、動作していません。…」と表示されパッケージのインストールに失敗する。

ちなみに、adbには、エミュレータも実機も認識されているように見えます。
実機では、デバッグターゲットにもちゃんと表示され、パッケージのインストールもうまく行きます。

※:1 Android SDK Managerからインストールしたパッケージ:

```
Tools以下全部
Android N(API 24)以下全部
Android N(API 23,N Preview)以下全部
Android 6.0(API 23)以下全部
Android 4.4.2(API 19)
    SDK Platform 19 4
    Intel x86 Atom System Image 19 5
Extras
    Android Support Repository 33
    Google USB Driver 11
    Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) 6.0.1
```

※:2 AVD Managerから起動したエミュレータの設定:

```
AVD Name:AVDtest01
Device:Nexus 4
Target:Android 4.4.2 - API Level 19
CPU/ABI:Intel Atom(x86)
Keybord:「Hardware keyboard Present」にチェック
Skin:WXGA720
Front Camera:None
Back Camera:None
Memory Options:RAM:512 VM Heep:64
Internal Storage:200
Emulation Options:「Use Host GPU」にチェック
```

※:3 実行環境(Win7 32bit):

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01055

Visual C++ for Cross Platform Mobile Development   1.0
Visual C++ for Cross Platform Mobile Development

Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova   Update 7
Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova

Xamarin   4.0.0.1717 (1390b70)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.Android   6.0.0.35 (d300845)
Visual Studio plugin to enable development for Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.iOS   9.3.99.33 (ea30b32)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS.

Android SDK Manager
Revision 25.1.7
```

以上、よろしくお願い致します。

---

レジストリとパスの設定を追記します。

1.レジストリの設定

自分の環境では「HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools」に
　存在したので、手作業で追加しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

2.「adb.exe」のディレクトリ確認(dirコマンド実行結果の一部)

C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools のディレクトリ

2016/06/20  01:18              .
　　2016/06/20  01:18              ..
　　2016/06/20  01:18         1,479,680 adb.exe

3.環境変数「Path」の設定

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

4.「adb devices」の実行結果

C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
　List of devices attached
　emulator-5554   device
　*************** device

あと、エミュレータを起動すると実機の方もデバッグターゲットに表示されなくなることも
あります。

Comment: プロジェクトの`minSdkVersion`はいくつでしょうか？（エミュレータはAndroid 4.4.2を指定して動いているので、`minSdkVersion`がそれ以降ならば動作対象外となるためデバッグターゲットには表示されません。実機が最近のものであれば、実機でだけ動作するのが説明できます）

Comment: 「AndroidManifest.xml」の「android:minSdkVersion」を4以下に設定すればよろしいのでしょうか？
「android:minSdkVersion」を「1」にしてVisual Studioを起動しなおしましたがデバッグターゲットは「使用可能なデバイスが存在しません」のままでした。

ちなみに、実機のＡｎｄｒｏｉｄのバージョンも4.4.2になります。

Androidの開発環境構築は初めてで分からない事だらけなので、この辺はご了承下さい。

Comment: `minSdkVersion`に指定する値は、API Level（4.4.2の場合は19、API Level 4以下＝Android 1.Xの端末は考慮しなくてよいです）ですので、そのままで問題ないですね。失礼しました。こちらもVSでのクロスプラットフォームには明るくないのでお力になれずすみません。[こちら](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/mt228282.aspx#ADB)は参照されましたか？

Comment: すみません回答の内容をよく理解していなかったようです。
「Native-Activity」で作成される「AndroidManifest.xml」の「android:minSdkVersion」の設定は「9(Android 2.3.1)」になっていました。
エミュレータは「19(Android 4.4.2)」で、minSdkVersionの方が以前となるので設定の問題はないようですね。
それと上記のサイトは、確認済みで原因の対象となりそうなものを試してみましたが解決できませんでした。
不勉強なため失礼なコメントをしてしまい申し訳ありませんでした。